# Augmented reality Chair does only show some parts?

Tags: 3d-view, export, transparency, gltf

I am trying to figure it out why the augmented reality chair only shows some of the texture, or all collections in one when using different web browsers.

We are creating a web shop where the client is able to choose the height and color of the chair. On the web shop it works perfectly, the client can check off his wishes. But when trying to use the AR function: only through google web browser on an Android phone does it show the correct outcome. When using an iPhone or using Google play Services for AR on an Android phone, it will show all layers of every height or only some of the texture?

What we don't know is if the problems lay within Blender and if there is something I can change, or maybe with the web?

Has anyone encountered a similar problem? of maybe has some advice to where I could find some answers?

In Blender, every mesh has its own material, all of them has been set to Blend mode: Alpha Clip.
Mesh that can change color, is linked through a GLTF settings node.
Mesh that don't change color is linked directly with the BSDF node.
I export the whole object with all layers as an (.glb/.gltf)

On the web shop, every mesh is linked to an outcome that corresponds with what should be visible. Example: Cushion black height 43 cm (BSDF) is linked to chair 43cm. Black wheels is linked to chair 43cm, chair 50cm and chair 62cm because it should show on all 3 chairs height.
Cushion color height 50 cm(This cushion is able to change color, GLTF) is linked to chair height 50 cm and Hex colors for red, orange, black and blue.

Here are some mobile Screenshots and a screenshot of the web shop check off (language Dutch):

Android Google play service (How it should not be)

[image: Android Google play service (How it should not be)]
[image: Android Google play service (How it should not be)]
[image: Android Google play service (How it should not be)]
[image: Android Google play service (How it should not be)]

Android Google web (working correctly)

[image: Android Google web (working correctly)]
[image: Android Google web (working correctly)]

iPhone (How it should not be)

[image: iPhone (How it should not be)]

Webshop (Working correctly)

[image: Webshop (Working correctly)]

Comment: I should also mention that to view the chair, you can or go to the web on your phone and choose the AR button, or scan the QR code from your PC.